# how to specify a list for a `for` loop on the command line in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, for-loop

I want to specify a list of non-consecutive numbers on the command line, like so:

```
for i in (50 89 132 17 55); do
      echo $i
done
```

How do I specify the list so that `$i` takes each of the values in turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just skip the parentheses.

```
for i in 50 89 132 17 55; do
      echo $i
done
```